# How do I install a specific version of python on alpine linux (python3.8)?

Tags: lambda, python-3.8, alpine-linux, sam

Currently I'm using a dind configuration in gitlab
This dind works for me to deploy a dockerized lambda function through SAM.

This is my before script

```
   - apk add --no-cache curl jq
   - apk add --no-cache python3 python3-dev py3-setuptools
   - apk add py3-pip
   - apk add --no-cache build-base g++ make cmake unzip curl-dev
   - apk add --no-cache autoconf automake libtool libexecinfo-dev
   - apk add --no-cache git
   - pip3 install --no-cache --upgrade wheel
   - pip3 install awscli --upgrade
   - pip3 install aws-sam-cli --upgrade
```

I'm having troubles because the lambda function python version is 3.8 an `sam builds` complains that the version the docker gitlab setup is different and doesn't find 3.8

Comment: What is the Alpine Linux version? Which python3 is being currently installed?

Comment: cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Alpine Linux"
ID=alpine
VERSION_ID=3.15.0
PRETTY_NAME="Alpine Linux v3.15"
HOME_URL="https://alpinelinux.org/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/"
as for the python version that gets installed:
python3 --version
Python 3.9.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solve it
Probably I lacked context
I'm doing a gitlab.yaml file to build, test and deploy my application in AWS thorugh SAM.

Since one of my lambda functions is a dockerized lambda function I nee sam to be able to access `docker` as a command so it can run `docker pull` and `docker build`
The other lambda functions that I have use python3.8 as runtime so the docker version I was using as a base image pointed to `https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.15/main/x86_64/` so everyt time something was installed with `apk` the version was 3.15 which has python3.10.
A solution to this is use:
`image: docker:19.03.15-alpine3.13` as a base image with the service dind like this:

```
image: docker:19.03.15-alpine3.13
## This will run a Docker daemon in a container (Docker-In-Docker), which will
## be available at thedockerhost:2375. If you make e.g. port 5000 public in Docker
## (`docker run -p 5000:5000 yourimage`) it will be exposed at thedockerhost:5000.
services:
  - name: docker:dind
    alias: thedockerhost

variables:
  # Tell docker CLI how to talk to Docker daemon; see
  # https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html#use-docker-in-docker-executor
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://thedockerhost:2375/
  # DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2375/
  # Use the overlays driver for improved performance:
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  REPOSITORY_URL: ######.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/
  REGION: us-east-2

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
    - apk add --no-cache python3
    - apk add --no-cache curl jq
    - apk add --no-cache python3-dev py3-setuptools
    - apk add --no-cache py3-pip
    - apk add --no-cache py-pip
    - apk add --no-cache build-base g++ make cmake unzip curl-dev
    - apk add --no-cache autoconf automake libtool libexecinfo-dev
    - apk add --no-cache git
    - pip3 install --no-cache --upgrade wheel
    - pip3 install --no-cache awscli --upgrade
    - pip3 install --no-cache aws-sam-cli --upgrade
  script:
    - aws ecr get-login-password --region ${REGION} | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${REPOSITORY_URL}
    - sam build
    - sam deploy --no-confirm-changeset --no-fail-on-empty-changeset
  only:
    - master
```

This alphine version points to:
`https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.13/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz`
which installs python3.8 and now sam is able to package/build the rest of the lambda functions.